# How to set animated DAE object to specific frame in Papervision

Tags: animation, papervision3d, collada

I have a object of type DAE and want to do something like

```
animatedDae.setFrame(15);
```

Any ideas how to do that in PaperVision3D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ultimately solved this by hacking a setFrame function into PaperVision

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the frame into time.

```
theDAEmodel.animation.channel.update(specificTimeNumber);
```